# VB code to add a sheet to a workbook in Excel

Tags: vb.net, ole

I use oleautomation in dBase to add a sheet to a workbook in Excel. The MS docs show the following syntax for VB:

expression.Add (Before, After, Count, Type)

taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add

I want to add the sheet after the last sheet, which means that I am not submitting the first parameter. Typically, I then substitute the "missing" parameter with a null. This does however generate an error:
error: Ole Dispatch Exception: Unable to get the Add property of the Sheets class

Could someone post the VB syntax to add a sheet after "Sheet1"?

Thanks,
Gaetano.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count`

Comment: The other parameters are Optional, so it is enough to write the one you need. Of course, instead of `ActiveWorkbook` you should use any existing Workbook object. If `dBase` needs the parenthesis, you should use them. In VBA they are used only if you try setting a sheet object. Something like: `Dim sh As Worksheet`, followed by `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)`.

Comment: I don't have that option in oleautomation, I need something like: oExcel.sheets.add(null,oExcel.sheets("Sheet1")), but the null is not accepted for the empty variant value. It may be a bug in dBase... unless there is a different way to pass an empty variant in oleautomation

Comment: It should not be an empty `String`. It should be an empty object. In VBA we may use `nothing`...

Comment: I tried both "nothing", still no success - it feels like it's a bug in the way that dBase submits this parameter to the OLE server. In all other cases, I just supply a null and that takes care of the empty parameters. Thanks for your help!